# auto run a php file

Tags: php

Is there a way to run a second PHP file from the first file ?

example i wam running a.php and from the foreach loop, the var is past to b.php using POST function..

Comment: I highly recomend to dont use global variables, or pass to each file through $GLOBAL or $_POST, create a Singleton class that handle all the global information.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [`include`](http://php.net/include) and you do not have to POST a variable, an included PHP file runs in the same scope as the including file (there's no HTTP request being made).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass it with GET.  You can just use `include('path/to/file.php')`.  That calls that file, and PHP acts as though the contents of that file were right there in the current one.

Comment: Note that you do not necessarily need the parentheses, `include` is a language construct, just like `echo` (even if it is listed as function on php.net). Have a look at the examples on http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php